# CSS Sideblock menu at correct position

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am trying to create the following menu:

[image]

I have started with building the css however i am not qute sure how to position the box correctly Here is what i have:

```css
.menu-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu-li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a {
  font-family: Titillium Web;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: #323232;
  text-decoration: none;
}
button {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
}

li:hover {
  color: #DB091C;
}
.sub-menu-ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}
.sub-menu-li {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sub-menu-li:hover{
  border-top: 1px solid #DB091C

}
hr.solid {
  border-top: 3px solid #bbb;
}

.openBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 323px;
  height: 687px;
  left: 384px;
  top: 198px;

  /* Hvid */
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px">
      <nav class="animate__animated animate__bounce animate__slow">
        <ul class="menu-ul">
            <li class="menu-li">
            <button href="" >Title </button> <sdk-icon style="float: right; padding: 5px" icon="fal fa-angle-down"
              altMessage="Åben" isFontawesome="true"></sdk-icon>
            </li>
             <div style="display: block" class="">
               <ul class="sub-menu-ul slide-in-left">
                  <li class="sub-menu-li">
                    <button>
                          Sub menu item2
                    </button>
                    <span>
                      <sdk-icon style="float: right; padding: 5px" icon="fal fa-angle-right"
                    altMessage="Åben" isFontawesome="true"></sdk-icon>
                    </span>
                  </li>
                  </li>
                  <li class="sub-menu-li">
                    <button>
                          Sub menu item2
                    </button>
                    <span>
                      <sdk-icon style="float: right; padding: 5px" icon="fal fa-angle-right"
                    altMessage="Åben" isFontawesome="true"></sdk-icon>
                    </span>
                  </li>
               </ul>
              </div>
            <li class="menu-li"><button href="" >Title 2</button>  <sdk-icon style="float: right; padding: 5px" icon="fal fa-angle-down"
              altMessage="Åben" isFontawesome="true"></sdk-icon></li>
            <li class="menu-li"><button href="" >Title 2</button>  <sdk-icon style="float: right; padding: 5px" icon="fal fa-angle-down"
              altMessage="Åben" isFontawesome="true"></sdk-icon></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="openBox">
       <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

How can i ensure that the box matches the outer menu (as shown on the picture)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better if you change your HTML a little bit, something like:

```
    <nav>
       <ul class="nav-menu">
           <li class="nav-item">Item 1</li>
           <li class="nav-item sub-item">
               Item 2 - Has sub-menu
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item sub-item">
                        Item 2 - Sub-menu - Has sub-menu
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="nav-item">Item 2 - Sub-sub-menu</li>
                            <li class="nav-item">Item 2 - Sub-sub-menu</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">Item 2 - Sub-menu</li>
                    <li class="nav-item">Item 2 - Sub-menu</li>
                    <li class="nav-item">Item 2 - Sub-menu</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
           <li class="nav-item">Item 3</li>
           <li class="nav-item">Item 4</li>
       </ul>
   </nav>
```

Then in your CSS you can add:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav {
    width: 300px;
}

.nav-item {
    padding: 4px 0;
}

.nav-menu,
.sub-item {
    position: relative;
 }

 .nav-menu {
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

 .sub-menu {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 100%;
     width: 300px;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
```

Hope it works for you now. The strategy is always the same, just define your sub-menus inside the .list-item you want to have a .sub-menu. Then give that item a position relative and to the sub-menu position absolute.

If you want the first layer to be on top like the image you show, just add a position relative to .nav-menu and remove .sub-item from the first layer lis.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) i think there is a little mistake though the menu is in three layers:

Menu, Sub menu and then the box i think yours is only the menu and the sub menu is it possible to to add an extra layer?

Comment: Edited response with another layer example. The logic is always the same regardless of the number of layers you want to add.